# catkin_make and target_link_libraries cant find file

Tags: c++, cmake, ros, catkin

I'm having trouble building this ros project with `catkin_make`. I'm getting an error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldofbot_kinemarics` which I believe relates to this line in CMakeLists.txt: `target_link_libraries(dofbot_kinematics_fk ${catkin_LIBRARIES} libdofbot_kinemarics.so)`

Below is my directory structure:

> - dofbot_ws
>
>   - src
>
>     - dofbot_moveit
>
>       - include
>
>         - dofbot_moveit
>
>           - libdofbot_kinemarics.so
>           - dofbot_kinemarics.h
>       - launch
>       - src
>
>         - 01_random_move.cpp
>         - 02_motion_plan.cpp
>         - 03_attached_object.cpp
>         - dofbot_kinematics_fk.cpp
>         - dofbot_kinematics_ik.cpp
>         - CMakeLists.txt

and my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(dofbot_moveit)
add_definitions(--std=c++11 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
        roscpp
        rosmsg
        rospy
        moveit_core
        moveit_msgs
        moveit_ros_move_group
        moveit_ros_planning_interface
        )
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets PrintSupport)
include_directories(
        include/dofbot_moveit
        ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(dofbot_kinematics_fk src/dofbot_kinematics_fk.cpp)
add_executable(dofbot_kinematics_ik src/dofbot_kinematics_ik.cpp)
target_link_libraries(dofbot_kinematics_fk ${catkin_LIBRARIES} libdofbot_kinemarics.so)
target_link_libraries(dofbot_kinematics_ik ${catkin_LIBRARIES} libdofbot_kinemarics.so)
add_executable(01_random_move src/01_random_move.cpp)
add_executable(02_motion_plan src/02_motion_plan.cpp)
add_executable(03_attached_object src/03_attached_object.cpp)
target_link_libraries(01_random_move ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(02_motion_plan ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(03_attached_object ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Here is `dofbot_kinematics_fk.cpp`

```
#include "dofbot_kinemarics.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace KDL;
using namespace std;
Dofbot dofbot = Dofbot();

const float RA2DE = 180.0f / M_PI;

const float DE2RA = M_PI / 180.0f;
const char *urdf_file = "/home/dofbot/dofbot_ws/src/dofbot_moveit/urdf/dofbot.urdf";


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

//    double joints[]{90, 90, 90, 90, 90};
    double joints[]{90, 135, 0, 0, 90};

    vector<double> initjoints;

    vector<double> initpos;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) initjoints.push_back((joints[i] - 90) * DE2RA);

    dofbot.dofbot_getFK(urdf_file, initjoints, initpos);
    cout <<fixed<< "FK kinematics result : " << endl;
    cout << "Xcoordinate (cm)： " << initpos.at(0) * 100 << "\t"
         << "Ycoordinate (cm)： " << initpos.at(1) * 100 << "\t"
         << "Zcoordinate (cm)： " << initpos.at(2) * 100 << endl;
    cout << "Roll  (°)： " << initpos.at(3) * RA2DE << "\t"
         << "Pitch (°)： " << initpos.at(4) * RA2DE << "\t"
         << "Yaw   (°)： " << initpos.at(5) * RA2DE << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dofbot_moveit/CMakeFiles/dofbot_kinematics_ik.dir/build.make:197: /home/dofbot/dofbot_ws/devel/lib/dofbot_moveit/dofbot_kinematics_ik] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2974: dofbot_moveit/CMakeFiles/dofbot_kinematics_ik.dir/all] Error 2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldofbot_kinemarics
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dofbot_moveit/CMakeFiles/dofbot_kinematics_fk.dir/build.make:197: /home/dofbot/dofbot_ws/devel/lib/dofbot_moveit/dofbot_kinematics_fk] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3433: dofbot_moveit/CMakeFiles/dofbot_kinematics_fk.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Why can't catkin_make find `libdofbot_kinemarics.so`?

Update:

I altered CMakeLists.txt with the following:

```
find_library(LIBDOF libdofbot_kinemarics.so <path/to/.so/file)
target_link_libraries(dofbot_kinematics_fk ${catkin_LIBRARIES} "${LIBDOF}")
target_link_libraries(dofbot_kinematics_ik ${catkin_LIBRARIES} "${LIBDOF}")
```

then I got a new error:

```
/usr/bin/ld:libdofbot_kinemarics.so: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: does the  `.so` file exists? You also don't have a `catkin_package()` in your `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo. Instead of `kinemaRics` it should be `kinemaTics`. Part of your folder structure uses `kinemarics` while your `CMakelists.txt` file declares/uses `kinematics`.

Comment: Thanks. I Don't believe it is a typo, I double checked everything. Some files are intentionally kinemarics and some are kinematics.

Comment: What about `add_executable(dofbot_kinematics_fk src/dofbot_kinematics_fk.cpp)` and `add_executable(dofbot_kinematics_ik src/dofbot_kinematics_ik.cpp)`, those files haven't been shown in your folder structure, and you also don't provide an `add_library()` to use the libraries `libdofbot_kinemarics.so`.

Comment: Ah thank you, the spelling error was in the question not the actual code. I edited the folder structure. ```dofbot_kinematics_ik.cpp```, ```dofbot_kinematics_fk.cpp``` are now spelled correctly in the original question.